# multiple values as input parameter for CDS consumption view

Tags: sapui5, abap, cds, amdp

is there a way to pass multiple values as input parameter, if the CDS View is a consumption view consumed by a list report template?

As far as I found out you could achieve this by calling the CDS with a ABAP program and pass select options but in our case the CDS should be consumed by a list report template.

Comment: What kind of "template" do you mean in this context? Also, you tagged this question as "ABAP-managed Database Procedures", but the text doesn't mention them. What's the connection?

Comment: It's the ALP Template provided by Business Application Studio / WebIDE. I also have a AMDP class connected to the CDS view

Comment: @Philipp: Do you have any idea maybe?